# Bathroom faucet issue

Tags: plumbing

We recently completed a bathroom remodel. The counter top was supposed to be templates for a center set faucet but was not. My contractor went out and got a new faucet to fit. We are finding occasional puddles of water and trying to figure out where the leak may be coming from. The other issue is they are flush against the backsplash making them impossible to clean behind.

Comment: Please take the Tour: https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour to get some info on how to ask for assistance here. As written, this lacks detail and concrete questions.

Comment: Where are the puddles?  Plumbing leaks are usually at connections, so would probably be below.  Puddles on the counter top usually from people not wiping up.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line here is that you did not get what you wanted (contracted for).
You need to be firm with the contractor to have the work done properly.
The fact that you have leaks tell me that there is not a "pride in work" going on.  No good plumber would leave a job without checking for leaks. A good GC will be sure the subs do their jobs properly.
Now you are stuck with an unacceptable situation. Ask the GC to correct it properly.